# convergence in measure with sequence of random variables

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

I got stuck on the below problem.

Suppose that $g:R\rightarrow R$ is a bounded continuous function and $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of r.v.s. Show that there exists a subsequence $\{X_{n'}\}$ of $\{X_n\}$ and a subprobability measure $\mu$ such that $Eg(X_{n'}) \rightarrow \int g(x)d\mu(x).$

How could I start to solve this problem?